# How to properly trigger a soft reset on ARM Cortex R52?

Tags: arm, reset, cortex-r52

I am porting a running project from Cortex M(Armv7) to Cortex R52(Armv8). On the former I just wrote VECTKEY(0x05FA) to AIRCR register which issued a soft reset immediately, without resetting all the peripherals. But I am not able to find a way to do the same on the R52. The closest thing I found is Hypervisor Reset Management Register, and writing to bit RR to perform a 'WARM' reset. But I am not sure of which all peripherals get reset with this.

Additional info: I am particularly interested in having the Performance Monitor Counter running through the reset as I need to measure the cycle count during the reset. And hence I want to make sure that the PMCCNTR is not reset.